# Data not displayed on a derby database

Tags: java, netbeans

So I've designed a simple production app and i am on the coding and testing stage. When i click the save button during the run process, it says "Record has been inserted" but i cannot see it on the inbuilt derby database on my net beans IDE what could be the problem? here is the sample code.

```
String mk = jTextField1.getText();
String mn = jTextField2.getText();
String ab = (String) jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
String bc = (String) jComboBox2.getSelectedItem();

try {
    Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver").newInstance();
    Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/production");
    {
        String host = "jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/production";

        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        String query = "update PRODUCT set FACTORY=?,PRODUCT_NAME =?,UNIT=?,OPENING_BALANCE=?";
        try (PreparedStatement update = con.prepareStatement(query)) {
            update.setString(1, ab);
            update.setString(2, mk);
            update.setString(3, bc);
            update.setString(4, mn);

            update.executeUpdate();

            jTextField1.setText(null);
            jTextField2.setText(null);
            MainPanel.removeAll();
            MainPanel.add(jPanelStart1);
            MainPanel.repaint();
            MainPanel.revalidate();
        }
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Record has been inserted");

    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "invalid entry");

}
```

Comment: Where is your insert query?

Comment: i used the update query, could that be the problem?

Comment: You want to update an existing record or insert a new one? If you want to insert a new one then use Insert query.

Comment: Use `INSERT` to insert a new record.

Use `UPDATE` to update an existing record.

Comment: i used the insert command but still not working, is there any error with this code?                                                                                           String query = "insert into PRODUCT 
   (FACTORY,PRODUCT_NAME,UNIT,OPENING_BALANCE)" + 
    "values (?,?,?,?)";
                     try  (PreparedStatement update = 
          con.prepareStatement(query)){
                            update.setString(1, ab);
                            update.setString(2, mk);
                            update.setString(3, bc);
                            update.setString(4, mn);

Comment: are you getting any exception?

Comment: Yeah i get the 'invalid entry' display

Comment: Please paste the whole stack trace .

Comment: what stack trace, the program runs fine only that it doesnt store the data